# Show table row based on select in other row in pure CSS

Tags: css, css-selectors

I've seen [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46144459/hide-table-row-based-on-checkbox-in-pure-css), but mine is a little bit different.

Take the following HTML:

```
<tr>
  <td>
    <select id="show">
      <option>Show</option>
      <option>Don't show</option>
    </select>
  </td>
</tr>

<tr class="basedOnSelect">
  <!-- stuff here -->
</tr>
```

As implied, I want to show the second `tr` based on which option is selected in the `show` `select` element. I can do this in JavaScript, but I have seen little CSS hacks to do similar things based on check boxes in pure CSS.

The problem in my case appears to be that the `select` is too far down the tree to use sibling selectors to get the desired `tr`, and there is still no "parent" selector to use.

Is this possible?

Comment: Not do-able with css - there is no parent selector.  Things done with checkboxes are usually done with the checkbox being a sibling of what it is changing

Comment: The one-column table is just for illustration purposes. In my real application there are many columns.